# Deleting data from an MS Access Database with C# via button click

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am trying to delete Data from my database via a button click however I am currently getting the error:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters."

This is my code for the delete button:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\Foundation Degree\Year 2\Chris Ovia\Assignment2\Assignment2\BookSellersDatabase.mdb";
        tempTitle = txtTitle.Text;
        connect.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Book WHERE Title = tempTitle", connect);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted", "Deleted", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        connect.Close();

        //this.Refresh();
        //Application.DoEvents(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delete query should be

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Book WHERE Title ='" +  tempTitle + "'", connect);
```

Comment: Thank you that has worked :D

While I'm here, do you know how to make it so that it refreshes the form after it has deleted the data?

Comment: You will need to clear each textbox then. If you however use binding as a mechanism to bind textboxes to data, you can clear the information with a single line of code.

Comment: Using string interpolation (for better visuals), `OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand($"DELETE FROM Book WHERE Title ='"{ tempTitle }"'", connect);`.